# How do I Install OpenCV2

Tags: opencv2, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get image_transport to work, but when I tried both roscreate-pkg and catkin_create_kpg, I always get the error along the lines of "the dependency opencv2 is missing". I used locate for opencv2 and found opencv2 under /usr/include. How do I get it working with ROS Indigo? Do I still need vision_opencv and all the other libopencv* packages like described in this page (http://wiki.ros.org/opencv2). Any help would be greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194430/how-do-i-install-opencv2/) by [K. Zeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/18898/k.-zeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 23 on 2014-10-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

- You have to declare *opencv2* as an external dependency in your *CMakeLists.txt*. Similar to *eigen* and *opencv* in this example: http://wiki.ros.org/catkin/CMakeLists.txt#catkin_package.28.29
- You will have to add *opencv2* also to the target_link_libraries (in *CMakeLists.txt*)

Hope this helps

---

Originally posted by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) with karma: 862 on 2014-10-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/18898/k.-zeng/) on 2014-10-08**:\

1. Would something like the code below work?

   catkin_package(
   INCLUDE_DIRS include
   LIBRARIES image_mover
   CATKIN_DEPENDS cv_bridge image_transport
   DEPENDS system_lib opencv2
   )
2. I don't have a .cpp file in the package's src folder yet. Should I write that out first?

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/18898/k.-zeng/) on 2014-10-08**:
UPDATE: What I did in the above comment didn't work.

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2014-10-08**:
What is not working? Which steps are you taking? What is the output of catkin_make?

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/18898/k.-zeng/) on 2014-10-09**:
Never mind. What I ended up doing was the following:

```
find_package(OpenCV REQUIRED)
find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  cv_bridge
  image_transport
)
```

...

**Comment by [K. Zeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/18898/k.-zeng/) on 2014-10-09**:
...

```
target_link_libraries(publisher ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
...
target_link_libraries(publisher ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(subscriber ${OpenCV_LIBRARIES} ${catkin_LIBRARIES})
```

I also removed opencv and opencv2 from package.xml.

**Comment by [dmngu9](https://answers.ros.org/users/21514/dmngu9/) on 2015-05-08**:
hey, how did you setup opencv with ros indigo? i have a lot of problem with this. What did you put in you Cmakelist file and xml file

**Comment by [ct2034](https://answers.ros.org/users/12141/ct2034/) on 2015-09-14**:
I have not tested it under indigo, yet. Sorry